# Why does MVC throw a NullReferenceException when there seems to be no Null Reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC view that is throwing a NullReferenceException in the following code:

```
<div class="center-block text-center mb15">
    Showing @count of @Model.TotalItemCount results
</div>
```

So, I would expect that the error is that `Model` is null.  However, the code has already made it through the following code which appears earlier in the same view:

```
@{
    long count = Model.Count();
}
```

Stepping through the code shows that `count` is (in this case) 6, and `Model.TotalItemCount` is also 6, so there is no null reference.

But it's still throwing the exception!

Here's the weird bit, which makes no sense to me and is the crux of the question.  When the exception is thrown I get the following in Visual Studio:

[image]

This seems to indicate that the view that is being debugged is *different* to the view being displayed in the editor, but

- I have deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders and rebuilt the app, with no change, and
- This view has not been changed for a couple of months and works with other controller actions (it is a `Shared` view).

Stepping through the view prior to this line in the debugger, every line is highlighted correctly (yellow bar through all text).

Comment: Does doing Showing @Model.Count() of @Model.TotalItemCount results also throw the error?

Comment: Is `TotalItemCount` an auto-property?  Or does it have an implementation?  What is the implementation of `Count`?  I assume it's just `IEnumerable.Count()` but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: One more thing, I have noted in the past that the debugger sometimes misidentifies the line in Razor files that throws the actual error.  Can you share the entire view with us, snipping out the irrelevant HTML?

Comment: I notice you are checking Model.Count and not Model.Count() in the if, so not sure how the view compiles!

Comment: `Model` is an instance of Troy Goode's `IPagedList<T>`, and implements a `Count` property as well as inheriting from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer was to look a little wider.  Although the error was marked as shown in Visual Studio, and the exception indicated that it was thrown by the indicated line number, the exception was actually due to null reference about 5 lines later (the intervening lines are all HTML) where a property was accessed for a value that was, in fact, null.

Unfortunately Razor view debugging has not achieved the maturity it should have after this long.  Thanks for the input to all who commented.

Comment: Usually it means there are stale files being used, and usually restarting the IIS Express and/or VS and/or cleaning the solution helps. Otherwise debugging razor views works fine.